# Accessing MDF file thread safety

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, mdf

Is MDF file access (when attached to SQLEXPRESS) thread safe?

I have a local MDF file deployed along with my WPF client application.
I'm using the MDF file to persist some client-specific settings. There may be many threads SELECTing and UPDATEing the same rows at the same time and thus accessing the file via the SQL connection provider simultanously.

Now, what i'm asking is wether or not I can treat the thread syncronization the same way as I do with remote SQL SERVER databases (just leave all the work to the SQL connection provider) or do I have to wrap my DB calls inside a critical section?

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the answers, it's not clear what you're trying to do. As noted, the MDF is the core database file which you'll usually access through a database engine. What would help is knowing how you're accesing it - the connection string you're using, or if not the source code that demonstrates how you're modifying the MDF. Without these, it's not really clear what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really confused, it's a Microsoft SQL database running on a database server that manages table and row locking and conflicts as long as you use optimistic concurrency in your WHERE clauses when updating rows. For example

```
update settings set A = 'val' where A = 'old val'
```

so of course it's thread safe.

Comment: No, its a local file which is a part of my project. The project is a client exe which is deployed to hundreds of machines. Are you saying that it doesn't make any difference wether its an attached mdf file or a regular remote connection?

Comment: You are not accessing local file directly, you are accessing through sql server client to sql server storage engine wich access file.

Comment: @UriAbramson, you're not going to be able to attach a network file from multiple machines. You need to put that database on a server and change the connection string during deployment to something like `Server=serverName;Database=databaseName;User ID=userid;Password=pwd`.

Comment: @TheSolution The file is deployed with the application and each instance of the app accesses the file that was deployed along with it. Its not a remote database buddy.

Comment: @DinoM so are you saying that its absolutely thread safe?

Comment: No,it really depends on your isolation level how many users can access same table or row.But as far I understand you are probably not going to have problem with that because only one user is accessing you local database at time !

Comment: @UriAbramson, then what would the concern be. When you attach a database it's loaded onto the local SQL Express instance at runtime. It's just like loading one yourself and setting the connection string. It's thread safe.

Comment: I don't know - that's why i'm asking... There still might be a few differences for example - the file is being attached on application startup while the main sql server file is (probably) attached as long as the SQL SERVER service is running. So it's not EAXCTLY the same. The MDF file has to be available 100% of the time in my application otherwise people might lose money, that's why i'm making sure.

Comment: @UriAbramson, when you use the attach syntax it **literally** attaches the database to the local SQL Express instance, just like if you had done it by hand. It's just shorthand for getting it attached during a deployment. It is then released when the application is through with it and reattached on subsequent loads, but there is no issue my friend, it's a **real SQL Server database** and has all of the same abilities.

Answer (score 0):

MDF file is **Main Database File**.

You can't write to MDF file directly(theoretically),you are accessing through SQL Server engines and clients.

As for multiple `SELECT` and `UPDATE` you are relay on database **transaction isolation levels**(read commited,read uncommited,serializable,snapshots).

**[Isolation Levels in the Database Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**

Comment: the MDF file doesn't have to be the main database file of the server. It can be created using VS or some other way and accessed via SSMS while its being "attached" to the sql server instance.